# Immutable.js and Typescript

Tags: typescript, immutable.js

I am creating an Application using react-redux. In that i am using typescript and immutable.js. When i use immutable methods like updateIn(), for a typed object, it is throwing error.

Following is the code which i tried:

```
interface aType{
  id: number
}

function randFun(a:aType){
  a = a.updateIn([....]); //It is throwing error in this line of code.
}
randFun({id:2});
```

> Property 'updateIn' doesn't exist in on type {...}

How can i get rid of this error???

Comment: If you are going to use immutable js you have to give up using interfaces for your immutable objects so you would have to replace aType interface with Map interface in the immutable definition file

Comment: You may also check out https://github.com/engineforce/ImmutableAssign, which is a lightweight immutable helper that supports TypeScript type checking, and allows you to continue working with POJO (Plain Old JavaScript Object).

Answer (score 1):

As for TypeScript, it's because `updateIn` is not defined in `aType` interface. To fix it, you can write:

```
interface aType{
  id: number,
  updateIn(n: number): aType
}

function randFun(a:aType){
  let n = 5;    
  a = a.updateIn(n); // No error here
}
randFun({id:2}); // This still need to be fixed!
```

However, it can't work in JavaScript too because you can't call `updateIn` on `{id:2}` object.

Comment: updateIn() is an immutable.js method as i mention in the question.

Comment: Do you use definition file https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/blob/master/type-definitions/Immutable.d.ts for immutable.js?

Comment: Yeah i used  definition file